# C# EF SaveChanges dosen't save last value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bindinglist, savechanges

I have bindingList bound to TextBoxes. When I enter new value in textboxes and press save button the value from last Textbox dosen't save in database. But when I pressed Tab key before save button every values from texboxes were saved. How resolve this problem with unsaved last value?

....

```
BindingList<Zamo> myList;
pg = new PGEntities();
var query = (from zam in pg.Zamo where zam.ID == rekord.ID).Take(1);
myList = new BindingList<Zamo>(query.ToList());
zamoBindingSource.DataSource = myList;
```

....

```
private void SaveButton()
{
    pg.SaveChanges();
}
```

This occurs only when I save by button in BindingNavigation.

Comment: Thanks, focus resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the tab key it is getting saved? that probably means the **saveButton event** is reading the text before the entered text is considered. Try to lose focus on the textbox, then save.